# Removing junk character from XML payload

Tags: java, integration, sap-pi, sap-xi

Can anyone please tell me how to remove Junk characters from payload in Java?

```
××××¨×× ×- ×©×`
```

Sender system is sending file to SAP PI (middleware) to receiver. When the file received from SAP PI it is showing the junk character file.

Can any one tell me how to remove junk characters?

Thanks
Narendra

Comment: I think junk characters are present due to improper encoding used while reading and writing file. The reason you cannot remove junk characters from your side is because junk characters will not be same and can be many. If you are sure your file contains ASCII characters only then there is way.  Could you please provide more details about your question ?

Comment: @Narendra, Information not sufficient, add little bit more information to rectify your problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove non-ascii characters from your string using following code :

```
 String strWithoutNonASCII = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "").trim();
```

or Use `Apache Commons Lang` to escape the characters which can break xml

```
//escaping characters like &, <, >
strWithoutNonASCII = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(yourString);
```